# How to generate endpoints having StreamingResponseBody as return type using Swagger in a Java-Spring server app?

Tags: spring-boot, rest, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

I want to write a POST endpoint definition that returns as response ***StreamingResponseBody ***using Open API - Swagger. Since the data that should be downloaded is very huge, I found that instead of sending byte arrays would be more optimized to use Steaming.

```
      responses:
        200:
          description: Successful operation
          content:
            application/zip:
              schema:
                type: string
                format: binary
```

Using this definition, the generated api looks as follows:

```
   @RequestMapping(
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        value = "/samples/export",
        produces = { "application/zip" },
        consumes = { "application/json" }
    )
    default ResponseEntity<org.springframework.core.io.Resource> _getExport(
        @Parameter(name = "SearchCriteria", description = "Supplies the preview filters", required = true) @Valid @RequestBody List<SearchCriteria> searchCriteria
    ) {
        return getExport(searchCriteria);
    }
```

I also tried to map the types inside the plugin generator as follows:

```
  <typeMapping>                    string+binary=org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.StreamingResponseBody
  </typeMapping>
```

But doesnt perform the map correctly and produces compilation errors since OrgSpringframeworkWebServletMvcMethodAnnotationStreamingResponseBody does not exist:

```
  @RequestMapping(
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        value = "/samples/export",
        produces = { "application/zip" },
        consumes = { "application/json" }
    )
    default ResponseEntity<OrgSpringframeworkWebServletMvcMethodAnnotationStreamingResponseBody> _getExport(
        @Parameter(name = "SearchCriteria", description = "Supplies the preview filters", required = true) @Valid @RequestBody List<SearchCriteria> searchCriteria
    ) {
        return getExport(searchCriteria);
    }
```